# ASP.NET TextBox with Suggestions

Tags: c#, asp.net

here is the scenario, I have text box, if I type few characters in text box, a popup should open which should have list of values matches my text box entry from DB with check box. after selection of the values from popup, the selected values has to be in text box with delimiters.

type Joh in text box,
the popup should have all the Names starts with Joh with check box
after selecting John, John David, John Edward from popup,
the selected values has to be appear in text box like, John, John David, John Edward.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you written any code?  What have you tried?  You ask for *better* code, but don't elaborate on how yours could improve.

Comment: "Can anyone has better code" than what?  What have you tried?  I don't see any code in your post.  Just please don't query the db on keypress.

Comment: So you want us to just give you code for this? Come on now

Comment: Try emailing Scott Hanselman. I hear he replies to "Give me teh codez" emails.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You didn't specify if this is in a web page (ASP.NET using c#) or a Windows form.

For ASP.NET I like the Ajax Control Toolkit, and it has an AutoComplete control that you could use to do this.  http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/autocomplete/autocomplete.aspx

If you want it for a Windows Forms app, see here: http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/01/winforms-autocomplete-textbox-using-c.html

Comment: Good Answer, even though the question is questionable, the answer is polite and correct... like that.

Answer (score 3):

Try [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)